# Adding Parameter to Javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this is my simple hardcoded version.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.support.cors = true;
        var this_id = '123456789123456';
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'https://thisservice/delivery/'+this_id,
                  type: "get",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { },
                  success: function(response){
                      console.log(response);
                      var html = '';
                      html += '<tr>';
                      html += '<th>Customer Name: </th><td>'+response.custName+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line1:</th><td>'+response.addrLine1+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line2:</th><td>'+response.addrLine2+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line3:</th><td>'+response.addrLine3+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line4:</th><td>'+response.addrLine4+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line5:</th><td>'+response.addrLine5+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<th>Address Line6:</th><td>'+response.addrLine6+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';
                      html += '<th>Customer PostCode:</th><td>'+response.custPostCode+'</td>';
                      html += '</tr>';

                      $('#theDelivery').append(html);

                  }

              })});
```

the code above works perfectly fine, however im now working to make this_id as a url parameter, so when the webpage is called along with a valid 16th digit number as a substring, it will return the contents of the objects that i am trying to access from this webservice.

How exactly is it done? i have attempted to do this in the code below, but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getthisId(this_id){
    $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: 'https://thisservice/delivery/'+this_id,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: { this_id },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<th>Customer Name: </th><td>'+response.custName+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line1:</th><td>'+response.addrLine1+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line2:</th><td>'+response.addrLine2+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line3:</th><td>'+response.addrLine3+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line4:</th><td>'+response.addrLine4+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line5:</th><td>'+response.addrLine5+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<th>Address Line6:</th><td>'+response.addrLine6+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<th>Customer PostCode:</th><td>'+response.custPostCode+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';

            $('#theDelivery').append(html);

        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getthisId(this_id);
});
```

this error occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: this_id is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (1032987988503654:59)
at i (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2)
```

im very new to this, any help would be great :)

Comment: `data: { "parcel_id":this_id}`

Comment: If your URL is actually /delivery/12345, then you need to remove the data: parameter and just use `".../delivery/"+this_id` OR possibly `".../delivery/"+encodeURIComponent(this_id)` if there are special chars in it

Comment: 12345... up to 16 digits can be random. if its a valid barcode, this should return a result from the json webservice, the hardcoded version works with, var this_id = 12345... , then url: delivery+this_id.   im am now tryring to have this_id as a parameter in the url instead of a variable to get results from the  webservice, im still getting Uncaught reference error: this_id is not defined @mplungjan

Comment: Then you are calling  getthisId() or passing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this

```
'https://thisservice/delivery/?id='+this_id
```

Comment: why he has to do it that way?

Comment: because it may accept id in this way and he already getting error in previous method.

Comment: you are building the url with query parameters, but if he is using REST his url https://thisservice/delivery/'+this_id, is a valid url

Comment: i accept your opinion but in according example it is not working already so another valid option as mention above.

Answer (score 1):

The server side is expecting the value in a parameter named `parcel_id`, so you need to provide that as the key in the object you provide to `data`, like this:

```
data: { parcel_id: this_id },
```